# Unity Friction Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm having a simple cube which is my character that can jump on a moving quad (left to right vise-versa) having a collider with friction physics material.The issue i'm facing is when the character jumps on the moving quad, instead of carrying the character along with the quad it leaves the character, friction didn't happen between quad and character in order to carry the character.I tried playing around with physics settings and also tried with a cube instead of a quad.

Im tweeting the quad for animation(Dotween),character has collider (friction material),rigid-body (angular drag - 0.05,drag - 0)

Screenshot of my character and quads
[image: Screenshot of my character and quads]

My Issue of quad moving without character
[image: Issue of quad moving without character]

I don't understand this should be taken care of unity's physics engine.we shouldn't be configuring unnecessarily or am i missing something?

Comment: Are you moving both the character and the moving platforms with their rigibodies? or with their transforms? (Sounds like the platform is being moved with its transform rather then its rigidbody)

Comment: Yes for the platforms i'm tweening transforms position using DOTween's (DOMoveX),is it wrong?

Comment: I believe you can do DOTween's method with rigidbodies cant you?

Comment: After looking at their documentation yea you can use that same method with the rigidbody.

Comment: @Eddge It works!! thanks a lot